# File not found "location issue"?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

I'm stuck with a File Not Found issue with Nginx and FastCGI for PHP. Could someone have a look at my conf file?

```
server {

        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
        listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        server_name  localhost;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

        root   /var/www/site1;
        location / {
                index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location /doc {
                root   /usr/share;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }

        location /images {
                root   /usr/share;
                autoindex on;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your `fastcgi_param`s is wrong.

It should read:

```
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```